# Quelle terminaison à « Telτ la fleur, le papillon […] » ?

Tags: accord

Dans la phrase « Tel**τ** la fleur, le papillon étend ses pétales », est-ce que la terminaison tau doit s’accorder au féminin avec *fleur* ou au masculin avec *papillon* ?

Comment: C'est quoi la terminaison tau?

Comment: @Lambie j’ai utilisé un tau en tant que variable métasyntaxique pour signifier l’inconnue.

Comment: En programmation on parle de variable méta-syntaxique: toto, titi, tata, tutu
riri, fifi, loulou
plop, pouet, glop, boum, ploum, hop
bidon, truc, bidule, machin
bibi, didi, bla, blabla
ga, bu, zo, meu (nombres Shadoks 0 à 3)

Comment: @Lambie Ah, enfin un domaine où tu démontres ton expertise !

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, aussi pour les tuteurs fixés au bord des pots. Fixer au pot pourrait être n'importe où sur le pot. Il faut fare gaffe à la chute d'arraché.

Comment: @Lambie *La chute d'arraché* ? De haltérophilie à côté d'un pot de fleur ? Il faut faire gaffe, en effet !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'adjectif *tel* se réfère au papillon et s'accorde donc au masculin singulier.

> ***Tel** la fleur, **le** papillon étend ses pétales.*

On pourrait aussi écrire :

> ***Pareil** à la fleur, **le** papillon[...]*

A l'inverse, on met ***tel*** au féminin dans :

> *Les battues avaient repris, parce que **telle** le Phoenix, **la** Bête avait resuscité !*
> Pierre Perrin, *Le triangle du Gévaudan*, 1998.

Idem pour ***pareil*** :

> *L'anthologie, **pareille** au sabre d'un illustre professeur d'écriture, sauve les poètes et, au besoin, les assassine.*
> Robert Kem, *Au jour le jour, 1958.

Comment: Est-ce que tu comprends comment la question a été note 4? Terminaison tau??

Comment: @Lambie L'OP a posé une question pertinente car il peut y avoir hésitation sur l'accord. Les upvoteurs se la sont probablement aussi posée. **τ** représente clairement une inconnue ici. C'est une originalité de l'auteur qui n'a rien de choquant.

Comment: Alors oui, je vous confirme que j’ai utilisé le tau comme une inconnue, une variable métasyntaxique si vous préférez. J’ai préféré utiliser une lettre grecque que latine pour différencier les variables (la terminaison) des constantes (le reste de la phrase). Et mon choix s’est porté sur la lettre Tau en particulier pour Terminaison.
J’ai songé que c’était le moyen le plus immédiat de signaler une hésitation.